# Make an JLabel move with Key Bidings

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I have a short script made in swing, people keep telling me that I need to use Key bindings to get the Jlabel to move but I can't figure out how to do it. anyone have any idea on how to implement Key bindings in a way it works that does not use a Key Listener or that will be a problem if I add a button?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Screen extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    int x,y;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Screen frame = new Screen();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Screen() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, "p1");
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
    btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            CardLayout c =(CardLayout)(contentPane.getLayout());
            c.show(contentPane, "p2");
        }
    });
    btnPlay.setBounds(185, 164, 53, 23);
    panel.add(btnPlay);

    JLabel lblGame = new JLabel("Game");
    lblGame.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblGame.setBounds(189, 28, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblGame);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel_1, "p2");
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel player = new JLabel("P");
    player.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    player.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 27));
    player.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    player.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    player.setBounds(x, y, 51, 40);
        panel_1.add(player);
}
}
```

Comment: Excuse me you were just given a link to a tutorial that has a working example showing you how to use key bindings to move a label around a panel. Instead you delete your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535560/label-is-not-moving-in-cardlayout. You made absolutely no effort to understand the code in that link. We are not here to write the code for you. If there is something you don't understand about the `working example`, then you ask a question.

Comment: Please don't delete questions. Especially if others have contributed to the page. It's not fair to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most things, start having a look at the tutorials, [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), as pretty much any answer is simply going to be based on these

You could do something as simple as this...

```
import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Movable {
        public void changeLocation(int xDelta, int yDelta);
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Movable {

        private JLabel player;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(null);
            player = new JLabel("X");
            player.setSize(player.getPreferredSize());
            add(player);

            setupKeyBindings();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void setupKeyBindings() {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "up");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "down");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "right");

            int xDelta = player.getWidth();
            int yDelta = player.getHeight();

            am.put("up", new MoveAction(this, 0, -yDelta));
            am.put("down", new MoveAction(this, 0, yDelta));
            am.put("left", new MoveAction(this, -xDelta, 0));
            am.put("right", new MoveAction(this, xDelta, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void changeLocation(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
            int xPos = player.getX() + xDelta;
            int yPos = player.getY() + yDelta;
            if (xPos + player.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                xPos = getWidth() - player.getWidth();
            } else if (xPos < 0) {
                xPos = 0;
            }
            if (yPos + player.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                yPos = getHeight() - player.getHeight();
            } else if (xPos < 0) {
                yPos = 0;
            }
            player.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
        }

    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction{
        private Movable movable;
        private int xDelta;
        private int yDelta;

        public MoveAction(Movable movable, int xDelta, int yDelta) {
            this.movable = movable;
            this.xDelta = xDelta;
            this.yDelta = yDelta;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movable.changeLocation(xDelta, yDelta);
        }

    }

}
```

## Disclaimer...

As I have, repeatedly, told either you or your fellow class mates, you shouldn't be using components this way. Instead, you should be following a [custom painting route](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), which will provide you with greater flexibility and far less issues in the long run.

```
import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Movable {

        public void changeLocation(int xDelta, int yDelta);
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Movable {

        private Rectangle player;

        public TestPane() {
            String text = "X";
            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            int width = fm.stringWidth(text);
            int height = fm.getHeight();

            player = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

            setupKeyBindings();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void setupKeyBindings() {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "up");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "down");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "right");

            int xDelta = player.width;
            int yDelta = player.height;

            am.put("up", new MoveAction(this, 0, -yDelta));
            am.put("down", new MoveAction(this, 0, yDelta));
            am.put("left", new MoveAction(this, -xDelta, 0));
            am.put("right", new MoveAction(this, xDelta, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void changeLocation(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
            int xPos = player.x + xDelta;
            int yPos = player.y + yDelta;
            if (xPos + player.width > getWidth()) {
                xPos = getWidth() - player.width;
            } else if (xPos < 0) {
                xPos = 0;
            }
            if (yPos + player.height > getHeight()) {
                yPos = getHeight() - player.height;
            } else if (xPos < 0) {
                yPos = 0;
            }
            player.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.draw(player);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            g2d.drawString("X", player.x, player.y + fm.getAscent());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Movable movable;
        private int xDelta;
        private int yDelta;

        public MoveAction(Movable movable, int xDelta, int yDelta) {
            this.movable = movable;
            this.xDelta = xDelta;
            this.yDelta = yDelta;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movable.changeLocation(xDelta, yDelta);
        }

    }

}
```

You should also be making appropriate use layout managers. These will safe you a lot of hair and time.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: FYI, I already gave the OP a link to working examples using KeyBindings. Instead of asking specific questions. the OP deleted the question (you can find the link in my comment above) and just reposted his original code with no effort made to understand the example.

Comment: @camickr I’ve linked to the tutorial at least four times for the same piece of code been used in at least four other questions, so no ones listening - besides, the solution isn’t perfect 

Comment: I linked to my blog which contains working examples, comparing approaches using a KeyListener and Key Bindings. The Key Bindings code I suggest is similar to yours. It obviously isn't the only way to do it but the point is I don't believe in helping people who completely ignore suggestions given and make no attempt to understanding working code.. I was hoping you did as well, so I was giving you a heads up about the OP's attitude.

Comment: @camickr In most cases I’d agree - since this is only the first time I’ve seen this poster post this question I’m not going to jump all over them, despite the fact it looks similar to other questions I’ve seen yesterday (yes I actually checked), with any luck we’ve answered four or five other people’s questions. A better course of action (for you, since you have history with the op) would be to downvote and close the question as one of any available duplicates - maybe a question ban will shake them into action

Comment: `since this is only the first time I’ve seen this poster post this question` - I know it is the first time because he deleted the last question so nobody will know this is a duplicate. That is why I was warning you (and others with my comment to the question).