# Java KeyBindings stop working after a few seconds

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I'm trying to move from Java KeyListeners to KeyBindings for animating but they work for a few seconds and then completely stop. I'm printing messages to the console when the actions fire, and those messages stop, so it's not just the painting that isn't working, it's the firing of the actions when the keys are pressed.

My class extends JFrame, and I just add a JPanel to it, and add a JLabel to the JPanel. I use flags toggled by the Actions to indicate how the JLabel should move, and I use the JFrame's `actionPerformed` method to check the state of the flags and adjust the JLabel's location.

I've tried adding `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` inside the `getInputMap` method, but it made no difference.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class KeyBindingTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    long counter = 0;
    int speed = 5;
    boolean isUp = false, isDown = false, isLeft = false, isRight = false;
    JLabel j = new JLabel();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    Timer t;

    Action upPressed = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("up on");
            isUp = true;
        }
    };
    Action upReleased = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isUp = false;
            System.out.println("up off");
        }
    };
    Action downPressed = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("down on");
            isDown = true;
        }
    };
    Action downReleased = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("down off");
            isDown = false;
        }
    };
    Action leftPressed = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("left on");
            isLeft = true;
        }
    };
    Action leftReleased = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("left off");
            isLeft = false;
        }
    };
    Action rightPressed = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("right on");
            isRight = true;
        }
    };
    Action rightReleased = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("right off");
            isRight = false;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // The try/catch block prevents errors from crashing the program
                try {
                    KeyBindingTest window = new KeyBindingTest(); // Create and setup the main game window
                    window.run(); // show the new window
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void run() {
        this.setBounds(640, 400, 640, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        p.setVisible(true);
        p.setBackground(Color.blue);
        p.setOpaque(true);
        p.setFocusable(true);
        p.setLayout(null);
        j.setBounds(320, 200, 10, 10);
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.setBackground(Color.red);
        j.setOpaque(true);
        this.add(p);
        p.add(j);
        p.requestFocusInWindow();
        setupKeyBindings();
        t = new Timer(1000 / 40, this);
        t.start();
    }

    private void setupKeyBindings() {
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "moveUp");
        p.getActionMap().put("moveUp", upPressed);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W"), "stopUp");
        p.getActionMap().put("stopUp", upReleased);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "moveDown");
        p.getActionMap().put("moveDown", downPressed);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released S"), "stopDown");
        p.getActionMap().put("stopDown", downReleased);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "moveLeft");
        p.getActionMap().put("moveLeft", leftPressed);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "stopLeft");
        p.getActionMap().put("stopLeft", leftReleased);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "moveRight");
        p.getActionMap().put("moveRight", rightPressed);
        p.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "stopRight");
        p.getActionMap().put("stopRight", rightReleased);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println(counter);
        if (isUp) {
            j.setLocation(j.getX(), j.getY() - speed);
        }
        if (isDown) {
            j.setLocation(j.getX(), j.getY() + speed);
        }
        if (isLeft) {
            j.setLocation(j.getX() - speed, j.getY());
        }
        if (isRight) {
            j.setLocation(j.getX() + speed, j.getY());
        }
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, after lots of testing, I have no idea.  I've tried a variety of combinations and I can still get the same results.  Some times the bindings stop responding for a short period of time and restart, some times, they stop altogether.  I've used `KeyboardFocusManager.addKeyEventDispatcher` and can verify that the key strokes are still been registered/processed by the EDT, but for some reason they aren't been delivered to the component - I smell a bug, but I can't be sure

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I'm glad to hear I'm not losing my mind!

Comment: I’ve tried several other previous examples, which all work, the main difference is they use s custom painting route

Comment: I'm doing this as part of moving from KeyListeners/JComponents to KeyBindings/JComponents, so I may as well make the entire move to KeyBindings/Painting so I will get it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a personal thing, but, you will generally have less issues if you use something like `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false)` over
`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W")`

The equivalent for `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W")` would be `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true)`
I have been back and forward through your example, I've tried replacing `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W")` with `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false)` and it's equivalents; I've tried replacing the `boolean` flags with a `Set` and I still have the same issue

I then went and threw away your code and started with a new project.  First I tried a custom painting route, and that worked fine.  I then tried a component based route and that worked ...

So, while I still don't have an "answer" for why it's not working, I do have an example which does...

## Example

And because I actually had test my suggestions...

```
import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum Input {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Set<Input> inputs = new HashSet<>();

        private int delta = 4;

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Up.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Up.relesed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Down.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Down.relesed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Left.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Left.relesed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Right.pressed");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Right.relesed");

            actionMap.put("Up.pressed", new InputAction(Input.UP, true));
            actionMap.put("Up.relesed", new InputAction(Input.UP, false));
            actionMap.put("Down.pressed", new InputAction(Input.DOWN, true));
            actionMap.put("Down.relesed", new InputAction(Input.DOWN, false));
            actionMap.put("Left.pressed", new InputAction(Input.LEFT, true));
            actionMap.put("Left.relesed", new InputAction(Input.LEFT, false));
            actionMap.put("Right.pressed", new InputAction(Input.RIGHT, true));
            actionMap.put("Right.relesed", new InputAction(Input.RIGHT, false));

            setLayout(null);
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setBackground(Color.RED);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10);
            add(label);

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int xPos = label.getX();
                    int yPos = label.getY();
                    if (inputs.contains(Input.UP)) {
                        yPos -= delta;
                    }
                    if (inputs.contains(Input.DOWN)) {
                        yPos += delta;
                    }
                    if (inputs.contains(Input.LEFT)) {
                        xPos -= delta;
                    }
                    if (inputs.contains(Input.RIGHT)) {
                        xPos += delta;
                    }

                    if (xPos < 0) {
                        xPos = 0;
                    } else if (xPos + 10 > getWidth()) {
                        xPos = getWidth() - 10;
                    }
                    if (yPos < 0) {
                        yPos = 0;
                    } else if (yPos + 10 > getHeight()) {
                        yPos = getHeight() - 10;
                    }
                    label.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

//        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
//            super.paintComponent(g);
//            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
//            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
//            g2d.drawRect(xPos, yPos, 10, 10);
//            g2d.dispose();
//        }

        public class InputAction extends AbstractAction {
            private Input input;
            private boolean pressed;

            public InputAction(Input input, boolean pressed) {
                this.input = input;
                this.pressed = pressed;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (pressed) {
                    inputs.add(input);
                } else {
                    inputs.remove(input);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## A side note...

This "type" of question is getting asked a lot lately, I assume it's some kind of class assignment, as we've seen a number of variants of this style of code.  As we've repeatedly advised, using components in this way is ill-advised, they aren't really designed for this kind of thing.  You will get better (and easier) results using a custom painting route, as demonstrated in [Make an JLabel move with Key Bidings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536948/make-an-jlabel-move-with-key-bidings/50537185#50537185)